# delete email unless it contains specific words in the email/subject rule setup Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules

I am a part of a distribution list that can get thousands of emails a day, I need to create a rule that deletes these emails unless they contain specific words in the subject/email body.  Is this possible?

Outlook 2013.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible. Just create a rule with the following parameters:

1. Create a new rule and select **Apply a rule on messages I receive** template.
2. Leave conditions **empty** and confirm that the rule will be applied to every message you receive.
3. Select **delete it** (to delete to *Deleted Items*) or **permanently delete it** action.
4. Select **except if the subject or body contains specific words** and specify required words.
5. Name the rule and click Finish.

That's it.

Comment: In step 2, you may want to specify the To: or From: address so only messages sent to the distribution list are filtered.

Answer (score 0):

**Rule to Delete all emails coming from a distribution List except words in the Subject / Body:**

1. Move message sent to a public group to a folder (Sent to *people or public group*)
2. Move it to the *specified* folder.
3. Delete it
4. except if the subject or body contains *specific words*

**Your rule will look like this:**

> Apply this rule after the message arrives
>
> sent to ***MY_DISTRIBUTION_LIST***
>
> move it to the ***MY_FOLDER*** folder
>
> and delete it
>
> except if the subject or body contains ***MY_WORDS***

Hope that helps ! Thanks.